# Prove Big O notation with log

Tags: asymptotics

I need to prove 
$$
2n^2+5n+20log(n)=O(n^2)
$$

I know that the right needs change term to the greatest degree
I got:
$$
2n^2+5n+20log(n)≤2n^2+5n^2+...
$$

I want to how to deal with the log

Comment: simply log(n) < n

Comment: Note that $\ln(x)\le x-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a (logarithmic) graph will help:

[image]

Comment: That means I can replace $20logn$ by $n^2$ or directly replace $20logn$ to $n^2$

Comment: Or does it make any difference?

Comment: No.  Given that only the largest asymptotic term is relevant, my graph reveals that the logarithmic term will always be smaller than the $n^2$ term.  Hence the logarithm can be ignored when calculating the order.